# How can i attach to the click when a user presses "clear search input" in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

As you can see on [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/pages/../../docs/forms/forms-search.html) jQuery mobile renders an "X" at the right of the entered text in an input search box. How can I attach to the click-event of that "X"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('.ui-input-clear').live('click', function(e){
    alert('click!');
});
```

Is a good starting point. I use `live` as the searchbox isn't necessarily in the page on load.
This of course is nonspecific by using the class but if required can be made so.

**Update:** As of jQuery 1.7 `.live` is deprecated in favour of `.on`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('.ui-content').on('click', '.ui-input-clear', function(e){
    alert('click!');
});​
```

Comment: This might have worked in previous versions, but doesn't appear to work in 1.1.0. Clicking into the input field fires the click event, but clicking the "X" button does not fire the click event.

Comment: @commandelimited It still works. See: http://jsfiddle.net/p8AQx/ ; I have used the new .on command as live is now deprecated. Updating answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

bind `click` to the whole thing and then determine what was clicked with `event.target` which holds the originally clicked element as the event bubbles up.

A simple if that checks for some classes should do.

Start from binding click and sniffing what's clicked:

```
$(theinput).click(function(e){
console.log(e.target);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with **jQuery 1.9** and **jQuery Mobile 1.3**:

I Have the input inside a form so, suscribed the event to an element inside it:

```
   <form id="frmBusqueda" action="frmBusqueda">                              
                            <input name="txtBusqueda" id="txtBusqueda" placeholder="Nombre de producto"
                                value="" type="search" data-clear-btn="false" onkeyup="activarFiltro();">
                </form>


    $('#frmBusqueda').on('click', '.ui-input-clear', function (e) {
                alert('click!');
    })
```